# Find a peak in a signal

Tags: algorithm, plot, signal-processing

I want to know if there is any algorithm to find a peak in a signal in Java (Android). I'm working on ECG's signals, and I'm using a real time algorithm to draw the signal so each point that I'm receiving I'm drawing it directly so I don't have data for the next points.

The signal is like this

[image: Ecg signal]

Comment: Could you tell a bit more about the nature of the signal and the kind of peak you'd like to detect?

Comment: @harold it's about ECG's graphs, I need to detect peaks, and I'm drawing the signal in real-time, so that's why I don't have the value of the next point.

Comment: Voting to close as off-topic. Question belongs at Signal Processing, probably. http://dsp.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @cricket_007 Because I want to implement it in Java. So is just an algorithm to detect peaks in signal

Comment: Okay, but you've not said what or how you are reading this data using Java, so try to [edit] with some details

Comment: Haha, I would love an algorithm like this too—I’d apply it to the stock market and when it said, “PEAK!” I’d sell! You can have half the money I make!

Comment: if there is noise present then standard peak finding methods are not reliable and you need to filter out false peaks. So 1. FIR filter (beware shifts so filter evenly) 2. for each data point flag if it is rising (`+1`) or lowering (`-1`) or neither (`0`). 3. then enlarge  `+1,-1` into `0` evenly. 4. scan where `+1,-1` are neighboring there is your peak `+1,-1` is positive peak and `-1,+1` negative ...

Comment: for very noisy signals is the best you can do this: `p(t) = |signal(t) - sliding_average(signal(t))|` now find peaks in that but only if `p(t)>threshold`

Answer (score 1):

From past experience, I can suggest the following simplistic idea off the top of my head. I'm assuming you're looking for the big spike, right? If not, I think the below process will work. You just need to change your thresholds. Bear in mind, the idea below comes from experience but **isn't tested**!

1. Run the signal through a moving-average filter to smooth it out. (Critical!)
2. Find the discrete differential of this filtered signal.
3. Run the discrete differential through another moving average filter. (Also critical!)
4. At each zero-crossings in the smoothed differential signal, compare the point *n* (either the left or the right sample of the zero-crossing) to its equivalent on the original filtered signal (found in step 2). If this point is greater than some predetermined threshold, *n* is your big spike.

I hope this helps. Feel free to ask if you have any questions. I implemented a similar algorithm in C++ it might help to look at: https://github.com/sawbg/avda/blob/master/src/process.hpp.